# read null terminated string from byte vector in julia

Tags: julia, c-strings, null-terminated

I have a vector of type UInt8 and fixed length 10. I think it contains a null-terminated string but when I do String(v) it shows the string + all of the zeros of the rest of the vector.

```
v = zeros(UInt8, 10)
v[1:5] = Vector{UInt8}("hello")
String(v)
```

the output is "hello\0\0\0\0\0".

Either I'm packing it wrong or reading it wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: The resulting string is backed by an array of 10 bytes, including all the zeros (Julia strings are more like the ones in C++ than the ones in C, IIUC). So what is is that you actually expect? `"hello"`? `"hello\0"`?

Answer (score 3):

I use this snippet:

```
"""
    nullstring(Vector{UInt8})
Interpret a vector as null terminated string.
"""
nullstring(x::Vector{UInt8}) = String(x[1:findfirst(==(0), x) - 1])
```

Although I bet there are faster ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unsafe_string`: `unsafe_string(pointer(v))`, this does it without a copy, so is very fast. But @laborg's solution is better in almost all cases, because it's safe.
If you want both safety and maximal performance, you have to write a manual function yourself:

```
function get_string(v::Vector{UInt8})
    # Find first zero
    zeropos = 0
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(v)
        iszero(v[i]) && (zeropos = i; break)
    end
    iszero(zeropos) && error("Not null-terminated")
    GC.@preserve v unsafe_string(pointer(v), zeropos - 1)
end
```

But eh, what are the odds you REALLY need it to be that fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid copying bytes and preserve safety with the following code:

```
function nullstring!(x::Vector{UInt8})
    i = findfirst(iszero, x)
    SubString(String(x),1,i-1)
end
```

Note that after calling it x will be empty and the returned value is `Substring` rather than `String` but in many scenarios it does not matter. This code makes half allocations than code by @laborg and is slightly faster (around 10-20%). The code by Jacob is still unbeatable though.